# How to call Fortran OPEN function from C++

Tags: c++, fortran

I'm trying to call the Fortran "OPEN" function from C++ (imported from libgfortran.a). The "OPEN" function is not straight forward to call from C++ as it takes a list of named arguments, as apposed to having a straight forward list of arguments. In Fortran these named arguments can be called in any order, and any of the arguments can be excluded.

Fortran example:

```
OPEN(UNIT=11, FILE="my_file.dat", ERR=90)   #and there are many other possible arguments
```

In C++:

```
extern "C"
{
    void open(long* UNIT, <named arguments>);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long unit_num = 11;
    char my_file[] = "my_file.dat";
    open(&unit_num, my_file); //not sure how named arguments are specified here either
}
```

How do you specify these named arguments in C++? If this is not possible is there some other way to get Fortran to open a file and give me the unit number, or open a file using fopen and share it with the fortran runtime somehow (getting the unit number for that file).

Comment: Why do you want to open a Fortran unit/file in C++?  You can't really do anything (sensibly) with the unit in C++ directly.  If you want to do Fortran I/O handle the open in the Fortran run-time; if you want to do C++ I/O, open the file in the C++ run-time.

Comment: I'm wrapping a Fortran library in a c++ interface. I need the unit number in order to interact with this library (the library is used for parsing some elaborate data files). I'm trying to do this in a way were I don't need to write extra fortran code.

Comment: You can create a Fortran wrapper around the call to `open` which returns the unit number to your C++ outer.

Comment: I did think of doing that (this is my fallback position). I was just trying to keep things simple. Writing the Fortran code would be simple enough, but then you have to worry about building and linking it (the complexity comes with managing the toolchains)... maybe I should stop complaining and just do it that way ;)

Comment: Simple is good, but here is certainly a case where extra Fortran is simple.  Worth noting, though, that in the Fortran, the `open` isn't itself a function, and `unit=11` isn't an argument with keyword.  There will be underlying function calls in the run-time, but it'll be far from portable.

Comment: Fortran does not have an `OPEN` function.  Fortarn has an `OPEN` statement.  These are two entirely different things.